# Python Poetry Add <dependency> gives an error

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have been playing with poetry to manage my project.I recently refactored my project.And now when I try to add a dependency to the project, I get the following error.

```
$poetry add loguru      
Using version ^0.5.2 for loguru

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.0s)

[InvalidRequirement]
Invalid requirement, parse error at "'fantasy '"
```

Here's my pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "Global Fantasy League"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Pravesh Chapgain<spravesh1818@gmail.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
asyncpg = "^0.21.0"
psycopg2 = "^2.8.6"
alembic = "^1.4.2"
pre-commit = "^2.7.1"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"
mypy = "^0.782"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your project name can't contain spaces.

Try

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "global-fantasy-league"
```

instead.